# pig latin need data not in commom

Tags: apache-pig

Data1

```
1,a
2,b
3,c
4,d
5,e
```

Data2

```
1,a
2,g
3,j
4,b
5,c
6,d
7,e
```

Script

```
a =  load '/tmp/data/data1' using PigStorage(',') as (timestamp:chararray,constant:chararray);
b =  load '/tmp/data/data2' using PigStorage(',') as (timestamp:chararray,constant:chararray);
```

I need output only the constants which not common and present in data2 as below

```
2,g
3,j
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: i need the code which will give only the data which is not in data1 and is present in data2.

Answer (score 0):

`RIGHT OUTER JOIN` and `FILTER` where a.timestamp is null.That will give you all records in b that are not in a.

```
c = JOIN a BY (timestamp) RIGHT OUTER,b BY (timestamp);
d = FILTER c BY (a::timestamp is null);
DUMP d;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help VK_217. I am able to achieve what i am looking.